How to get the index of specific value in geonode

I want to obtain the index that has a value of true, in a single frame.
In this pic, for example, the result would be 8, how do I do that?

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Without any assumption about how many points with a value of True there is, a Separate Geometry node can extract a geometry with only such points (green graph part).
The case where there is none is treated by the blue graph part. A Domain Size node is counting how many points are extracted. If it is 0 (i.e. not Greater Than 0), -1 (i.e. an invalid Index value) is returned by the Switch node.
The case where there is at least one point with a value of True is treated by the red graph part. From the selected geometry, the first point position is recovered through a Sample Index node set in Point domain. It is to notice that the Index value is hardcoded to 0, to pick a single point even if more than one point were selected. Eventually, a Sample Nearest node on the original geometry at this position is returning the Index of the point of interest. Be aware that the Separate Geometry node might re-index points and consequently the first extracted point might not be the first tagged point in the original geometry order, if there is more than one.

For the demonstration, the point of interest is defined by its Index through the Group Input node, and the boolean to tag it is computed by a Capture Attribute node. The Viewer node should returned the Value entered in the Properties editor, or -1 for out of bounds values.
Resources: 

Too much belt-and-braces , I suppose, but as a supplement, you could use Accumulate Field (1) to check there was only one True element.

@RobinBetts: I appreciate your "belt-and-braces" mindset shown in your answers ! I took the opportunity of your comment to extend my first proposal, to deal with out of bounds cases (less or more than one True element).

Hehe... :) I guess GN is never going to be a 'safe' programming language, but we can do our best, where it's worth it.

You can also test against a value by comparing against it as an index.
In this case Blurred in positive and IndexofPoint is a Stored attribute that returns the Index number if Blurred is positive. Likewise you could use it to Switch between 2 values, in this case the Position.


Welcome to BSE! I think this doesn't answer the OP's question, because it just stores what you already have: index. But it won't tell you from outside the context of each element, what is the index of the element with a value of interest. Also notice the ambiguity for the first element.
